# i have problem to make inherit from other class

Tags: python, oop

**I just created three class for inheritance but something went wrong but I try to solve it but not work** 
I want to know what make this **Error** and how i should **solve it**
I should inherit from other classes

1. the Classes:

   - Property
   - House
   - Rental
   - HouseRental

why House Object takes no parameters

in Book python 3 object oriented Programming

This is slightly surprising, as it has neither an **init** nor display method! Because both parent classes appropriately call super in these methods, we only have to extend those classes and the classes will behave in the correct order. This is not the case with prompt_init, of course, since it is a static method that does not call super, so we implement this one explicitly. We should test this class to make sure it is behaving properly before we write the other three combinations:

```
def get_valid_input(input_string, valid_options):
    input_string += "({})".format(", ".join(valid_options))
    response = input(input_string)
    while response.lower() not in valid_options:
        response = input(input_string)
    return response

class Property:
    def __init__(self, baths="", square_feet="",
                 beds="", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_baths = baths
        self.square_feet = square_feet
        self.num_beds = beds

    def display(self):
        print("PROPERTY DETAILS")
        print("================")
        print("square footage: {}".format(self.square_feet))
        print("bedrooms: {}".format(self.num_bedrooms))
        print("bathrooms: {}".format(self.num_baths))
        print()

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        return dict(sqare_feet=input("Enter The Square:"),
                    num_beds=input("Enter the Number of beds"),
                    num_baths=input("Enter the Number of baths"),)
```

```
class House(Property):
    valid_garage = ("attached", "detached", "none")
    valid_fenced = ("yes", "no")

    def __init__(self, garage="", fenced="", num_stories="", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_stories = num_stories
        self.garage = garage
        self.fenced = fenced

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print("HOUSE DETAILS")
        print("# of stories: {}".format(self.num_stories))
        print("garage: {}".format(self.garage))
        print("fenced yard: {}".format(self.fenced))

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        parent_init = Property.prompt_init()
        garage = get_valid_input("Is the yard fenced? ", House.valid_garage)
        fenced = get_valid_input("Is there a garage? ", House.valid_fenced)
        num_stories = input("How many stories? ")

        parent_init.update({
            "garage": garage,
            "fenced": fenced,
            "num_stories": num_stories
        })
        return parent_init
```

```
class Rental:
    def __init__(self, furnished="", rent="", utilities="", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.furnished = furnished
        self.rent = rent
        self.utilities = utilities

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print("RENTAL DETAILS")
        print("rent: {}".format(self.rent))
        print("estimated utilities: {}".format(self.utilities))
        print("furnished: {}".format(self.furnished))

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        return dict(
                rent=input("What is the monthly rent? "),
                utilities=input("What are the estimated utilities? "),
                furnished=get_valid_input("Is the property furnished? ",       ("yes", "no")),)
```

```
class HouseRental(House, Rental):

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        init = House.prompt_init()
        init.update(Rental.prompt_init())
        return init

info = HouseRental().prompt_init()
o = HouseRental(**info)
o.display()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "estate/placement.py", line 148, in <module>
    o = HouseRental(**info)
  File "estate/placement.py", line 68, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "estate/placement.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "estate/placement.py", line 117, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Rental class, you have not specified a parent class, but you have called super().

Should Rental be a sub-class of Property?

If so, simply change that class to:

```
class Rental(Property):
def __init__(self, furnished="", rent="", utilities="", **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.furnished = furnished
    self.rent = rent
    self.utilities = utilities
```

Similarly, the class Property calls super() but inherits from no parent. I don't believe you intend for Property to be a sub-class, so remove the super() call:

```
class Property:
def __init__(self, baths="", square_feet="",
             beds="", **kwargs):
    self.num_baths = baths
    self.square_feet = square_feet
    self.num_beds = beds
```

More generally:
The form NewClass(ParentClass) induces the NewClass to inherit methods and properties from the ParentClass. Any arguments that taken by the **init** function of Parent class can now be safely passed to NewClass.
Calling super().**init**(**kwargs) takes any keyword arguments passed to NewClass and passes them on to ParentClass.

If there is no ParentClass, then the NewClass inherits from the Python base class Object, which takes no arguments. Passing (**kwargs) to Object throws an error.

The last line of your traceback describes this:

```
object.__init__() takes no parameters
```